# Windows Firewall Citrix Store App HDX Redirection without admin rights

Tags: windows, firewall, citrix

So our users will get Laptops soon and we're currently testing our setup.

One scenario is this:

User has no admin rights on the Windows 10 laptop. He downloads Citrix Workspace from the Windows Business Store and logs into a citrix session. When he starts an application that uses HDX redirection, e.g. Skype for Business, a Windows Firewall popup appears on the local machine and asks to add an exception to the firewall (which the user is not capable of doing as he's not admin on his local machine).

When setting a firewall exception via policy using the program path everytime the app ist updated from the windows store the firewall exception will become invalid as the path contains a version number and therefore changes with every version (which seems to be released every 2-4 weeks).

So I also tried to use a firewall exception using the appx sid instead:

`New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Test SID In" -Direction Inbound (respectively Outbound) -Action Allow -Package <sid>`

This doesn't work as the application triggering the firewall popup is contained in the app installation in path `"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\d50536cd.citrixreceier_20.10.11.0_x86__hmf6bx7z76t54\ica_client_mediaengineservice.exe"`.

I guess windows firewall doesn't recognise it as the same app, but I'm kinda lost here.

Any ideas how to handle this without creating a new firewall rule every time the Citrix workspace app updates?

Comment: What is the exact reason you want to specifically use the windows app instead of the exe installation? Because as you said, the folder location of the windows apps can change after an update.

Comment: Not every user needs the application so they can download it themselves. Even if we switch to an exe installation, what if another app behaves like this which doesn‘t have an exe version?